# Como mudar o nome PADRÃO na tag <input type ="date">

Tags: html, input, data

Estou colocando em um formulário um `input type=date` , com isso ele me retorna `mm/dd/aaaa`.

Gostaria que, ao invés de aparecer isso, aparecesse qualquer outra coisa que eu digitasse, como por exemplo "Data Inicial".

A tag `label`, colocaria um texto "Ao lado ou em cima".

Comment: Vc quer que o placeholder aparece o texto que vc definiu, ou vc quer que o cara possa digitar qualquer coisa dentro de um type =“date”? Não ficou muito claro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá.

Tente dessa forma e me retorne:

```
<input placeholder="Data Inicial" type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='text')" id="date">
```

Dessa forma fica melhor.

Comment: Só avisando que logo abaixo da resposta existe o botão "editar". Você pode utilizá-lo para alterar a sua resposta, não precisa excluir e criar outra. Aliás, muito cuidado com o ato de excluir, pois o sistema pune usuários que excluem conteúdo constantemente com suspensão.

Comment: Funcionou . Obrigado